# Entity manager in Controller Constructor Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I am writing a simple symfony2 application and I wanted to create a constructor for my Default Controller and have it run a query with doctrine. So I wrote something like:

```
public function __construct()
{
  $product = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('AcmeStoreBundle:Product')
    ->find($id);

  DefaultController::$products = $product;
}
```

The problem is that it says that there is a call to an undefined method on get(). What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a matter of dependency injection (DI) => You are in the constructor of the controller, and try to get the Doctrine object from your container. But this container is injected AFTER your object construction thanks to the DI.

So when you try to do the following :

```
$this->getDoctrine()...
```

it's quite normal that you don't have the methods on your container, because it doesn't exist yet in your controller.

Comment: That is what I thought but in this case how can I achieve what I want? I did try have the controller as a service but it didn't work as expected. Is there a standard way to do this?

Comment: I think you should try with an Event Listener: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html